# Chart.js modal window

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, chart.js

I'm trying to display a bar graph onto a pop-up modal window. I have managed to get the modal to work with a button but the graph won't appear.

Modal and button:

```
    <button id = 'btn' class= 'button'> 
        Data
    </button>

    <div id = "myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modalContent">
            <span class = "close"> &times; </span>
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Chart.js:

```
    function renderChart(data, labels) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [
                "GFA","GBA","NSA","FSR","Open Space Ratio","Sunlight Ratio","Ventilation Ratio","Stories"
                ],
                datasets: [{
                    label: labels,
                    data: [ 2.6, 30.6, 5.6, 6.4, 8.7, 2.1, 3.5, 9],
                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                }]
            },
        });
    }
```

Modal:

```
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function () {
        //modal.style.display = 'block'
        renderChart(data, labels);
    }

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.btn.onclick" for the line: "renderChart(data, labels);" but I'm not sure what the issue is.

I'm pretty new to code so I would really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code into the editor, added the Chart.js library via it's cdn, and the error was `data`, (or `labels` if I remove `data`) not being defined. It seems like you are trying to define `data`, and `labels`, but doing so inside the function `renderChart()`

With those arguments not required or passed to the function, it looks like the chart data is being rendered fine! Check out my working example:

```js
    function renderChart() {     
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [
                "GFA","GBA","NSA","FSR","Open Space Ratio","Sunlight Ratio","Ventilation Ratio","Stories"
                ],
                datasets: [{
                    label: this.labels,
                    data: [ 2.6, 30.6, 5.6, 6.4, 8.7, 2.1, 3.5, 9],
                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                }]
            },
        });
    }
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    btn.onclick = function () {
        modal.style.display = 'block'
        renderChart();
    }

    span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

```css
.modal {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button id = 'btn' class= 'button'> 
        Data
    </button>

    <div id = "myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modalContent">
            <span class = "close"> &times; </span>
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I also had to change the `labels` property to `this.labels` referring to the `labels` on the same object which it had been defined on.

Hopefully this helps get you on track

Comment: thank you! the rendering now works but the modal can only be closed and opened once. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Hi @JamieVincent , edited the example in 2 ways to achieve this: 1— defaulted the modal to `display: none;` with css (also added a black border so it's clear where it's boundaries are), 2— un-commented your line in the `btn.onclick` listener to change the modal to `display: block` before rendering the chart. Other that that your code seems to work fine. Have fun!