# Line chart not displaying correctly within modal box

Tags: html, jquery, amcharts

I am new to HTML jquery. I'm stuck on the below issue and unsure not sure how to go about solving it.

I have added a line chart onto a modal box. The chart displays, but only at half the height of the modal height, when I would have expected the entire modal height to be used.

My HTML code is follows

```
                    <div id = "myModal" class="modal">
                        <div class="modalContent">
                            <span class = "close"> </span>
                            <div id="data_chart"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The jquery function I use to create the chart is below, I left out some formatting codes for simplicity.

```
function renderChart() {

                      //===========================
                      var len = data_obj["trend"]["x"].length;
                      var trend_data = []

                      for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                          var d = new Date(data_obj["trend"]["x"][i]);
                          var t = {"date": d, "value": data_obj["trend"]["y"][i]};
                          trend_data.push(t)};


                      var chart = am4core.create("data_chart", am4charts.XYChart);
                      chart.data=trend_data;
                      var title = chart.titles.create();
                      title.text = "Pulse Index";
                      title.marginBottom = 30;
                      title.fontSize = 16;
                      var dateAxis_line = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
                      dateAxis_line.renderer.inside = true;
                      dateAxis_line.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

                      // Create value axis
                      var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
};
```

The output of the modal & chart shows the chart's height is not fully occupying the height of the modal box. I am not sure why.

[image]

For more detail, the DOM details are

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: The height of your modal is probably 0 untill you draw it and your AMChart code is probably executed on page load. => Try to render the chart when the modal is shown

Comment: that's a good point, but I do think the modal is shown before chart is rendered. this is code code that renders the chart.  `$("*[id='myModal']").css('display', 'block');
                        renderChart();`